# Put values in a column in Python using xlsxwriter. Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, report, xlsxwriter

I want to put this data in the following form using xlsxwriter, any help please?

```
'my_list': [
        {'field1': 'xxxxx', 'field2': [
                {'A': 'xxxx_01', 'B': 100
                },
                {'A': 'xxxx_02', 'B': 200
                },
                {'A': 'xxxx_03', 'B': 300
                },
                {'A': 'xxxx_04', 'B': 400
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a **valid** Python *input*. The one you gave, throws a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: this is the output of my list ; when traying with  sheet.write(row_num, col_num, key) , still have problem , @Timeless

Comment: But you did not read my comment. You should give a valid Python input.

Comment: I added the missing comma after the first list item